# Navigation bar underneath content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using this tutorial. So I have a navigation bar with image links that hides when the user scrolls down. 
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_navbar_hide_scroll

So this works, though.

However, when I scroll down, the images in the **body** show above the navigation bar. The text in the body is unaffected, however. **So my question is how to stop this from happening.** Another thing is how do I make the headline which is the orange "Sample Queen" to show up below the navigation bar, because it is now hidden underneath it. **I want the content to start below the navigation bar**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">



<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<script>
    /* When the user scrolls down, hide the navbar. When the user scrolls up, show the navbar */
var prevScrollpos = window.pageYOffset;
window.onscroll = function() {
  var currentScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
  if (prevScrollpos > currentScrollPos) {
    document.getElementById("navbar").style.top = "0";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("navbar").style.top = "-190px";
  }
  prevScrollpos = currentScrollPos;
}
</script>
<body style="font-family:Century Gothic;">

<div id="navbar"  style="background-color:#f1f1f1;padding:15px;text-align: center;">
    <img src="/Index Files/insta.png" id="border" alt="sample Queen" style="width:100px;height:100px;">
    <img src="/Index Files/sample.png" id="border" alt="sample Queen" style="width:100px;height:100px;">
    <img src="/Index Files/asample.png" id="border" alt="sample Queen" style="width:100px;height:100px;">
    <img src="/Index Files/amazon.jpg" id="border" alt="sample Queen" style="width:100px;height:100px;">
    <img src="/Index Files/sample.jpg" id="border" alt="sample Queen" style="width:100px;height:100px;">
    <img src="/Index Files/sampleos.jpg" id="border" alt="sample Queen" style="width:100px;height:100px;">
</div>    
<h1><font color="orange">sample Queen</font>
</h1>
<h2>sample Queen is a small soap businets </h2>
</head>



<p>________</p>
<div class="slideshow-container">
  <div class="mySlides1" >
    <img src="/sample Queen/fm1.jpg" id="border" style="width:100%">
  </div>
  <div class="mySlides1">
    <img src="/sample Queen/fm2.jpg" id="border" style="width:100%">
  </div>
  <div class="mySlides1">
    <img src="/sample Queen/fm3.jpg" id="border" style="width:100%">
  </div>
  <div class="mySlides1">
    <img src="/sample Queen/fm4.jpg" id="border" style="width:100%">
  </div>
  <div class="mySlides1">
    <img src="/sample Queen/fm5.jpg" id="border" style="width:100%">
  </div>
  <div class="mySlides1">
    <img src="/sample Queen/fm6.jpg" id="border" style="width:100%">
  </div>
  <div class="mySlides1">
    <img src="/sample Queen/fm7.jpg" id="border" style="width:100%">
  </div>
  <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1, 0)">&#10094;</a>
  <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1, 0)">&#10095;</a>
</div>

<p>________</p>
<div class="slideshow-container">
  <div class="mySlides2">
    <img src="/sample Queen/nd1.jpg" id="border" style="width:100%">
  </div>
  <div class="mySlides2">
    <img src="/sample Queen/nd2.jpg" id="border" style="width:100%">
  </div>
  <div class="mySlides2">
    <img src="/sample Queen/nd3.jpg" id="border" style="width:100%">
  </div>
  <div class="mySlides2">
    <img src="/sample Queen/nd4.jpg" id="border" style="width:100%">
  </div>
  <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1, 1)">&#10094;</a>
  <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1, 1)">&#10095;</a>
</div>

<p>________</p>
<div class="slideshow-container">
    <div class="mySlides3">
      <img src="/sample Queen/gel1.png" id="border" style="width:100%">
    </div>
    <div class="mySlides3">
      <img src="/sample Queen/herbal1.png" id="border" style="width:100%">
    </div>
    <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1, 2)">&#10094;</a>
    <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1, 2)">&#10095;</a>
</div>

<div class="slideshow-container">

    <p>________</p>

    <div class="mySlides5">
      <img src="/sample Queen/hs.jpg" id="border" style="width:100%">
    </div>
</div>

<p>________</p>
<div class="slideshow-container">
    <div class="mySlides4">
      <img src="/sample Queen/hairmask1.png" id="border" style="width:100%">
    </div>
    <div class="mySlides4">
        <img src="/sample Queen/lip.png" id="border" style="width:100%">
      </div>

    <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1, 3)">&#10094;</a>
    <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1, 3)">&#10095;</a>
</div>

<p></p>


<div id="imgGrey"  style="background-color:#f1f1f1;padding:15px;text-align: center;">

    </div>
    </div> 



    <script>
   var slideIndex = [1,1,1,1,1];
    var slideId = ["mySlides1", "mySlides2", "mySlides3", "mySlides4", "mySlides5"]
    showSlides(1, 0);
    showSlides(1, 1);
    showSlides(1, 2);
    showSlides(1, 3);
    showSlides(1, 4);


    function plusSlides(n, no) {
      showSlides(slideIndex[no] += n, no);
    }

    function showSlides(n, no) {
      var i;
      var x = document.getElementsByClassName(slideId[no]);
      if (n > x.length) {slideIndex[no] = 1}    
      if (n < 2) {slideIndex[no] = x.length}
      for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
         x[i].style.display = "none";  
      }
      x[slideIndex[no]-1].style.display = "block";  
    }
    </script>










    </body>



























</html>
```

```
 h1 {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: "Century Gothic";
    font-size:50px;
    font-weight: bold;

  }

  p {
    color: lightgrey;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: "Century Gothic";
    font-size:40px;

  }

  h2 {
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: "Century Gothic";
    font-size:20px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;


  }










    /* Now disable grayscale on hover */
    #border:hover {
    filter: none;
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(0);
    }


    #border {
    border-radius: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    filter: gray; /* For IE6-9 */
    filter: grayscale(1); /* For Microsoft Edge and Firefox 35+ */
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(1); /* For Google Chrome, Safari 6+ & Opera 15+ */

    }











    /* Slideshow container */
    .slideshow-container {
      max-width: 500px;
      position: relative;
      margin: auto;
      padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    }

    /* Next & previous buttons */
    .prev, .next {
      cursor: pointer;
      position: absolute;
      top: 40%;
      width: auto;
      padding: 20px;
      color: lightgrey;
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 18px;
      transition: 0.6s ease;
      border-radius: 0 10px 10px 0;
      user-select: none;
    }

    /* Position the "next button" to the right */
    .next {
      right: 0;
    }

    /* On hover, add a grey background color */
    .prev:hover, .next:hover {
      background-color: #f1f1f1;
      color: black;
    }








    /* width */
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 20px;
  }

  /* Track */
  ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px grey; 
    border-radius: 0px;
  }

  /* Handle */
  ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: lightgrey; 
    border-radius: 5px;
  }

  /* Handle on hover */
  ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
    background: orange; 
  }







  #navbar {
    background-color: #333; /* Black background color */
    position: fixed; /* Make it stick/fixed */
    top: 0; /* Stay on top */
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    transition: top 0.3s; /* Transition effect when sliding down (and up) */
  }

  /* Style the navbar links */
  #navbar a {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
  }

  #navbar a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
    color: black;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add the below lines to your CSS.

```
#navbar{
z-index: 1000;
}
body{
padding-top: 200px;
}
```

You may control the padding-top value according to the height of your navbar.

Comment: It worked, appreciate it. So could you walk me through what you did?

Comment: Your navbar was arranged on the plane which is lower than content. So the body content images were overlapping on the navbar. So I set the z-index property to 1000.
And when we are using the navbar we should consider the padding property so that the content would start after the navbar. the navbar position property is absolute so the content would start from the beginning of the body regardless of the navbar element

Comment: Would you please check the answer?

Comment: Done. Thank you for your help.